# Is @Configuration mandatory?

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

For some circumstances I've got an Spring configuration class that can not be annotated with `@Configuration`. At the beginning I thought that it couldn't work because Spring configuration must have `@Configuration` annotation. However, after doing some tests, I've just realized `@Configuration` is not mandatory.

For example, this is a configuration Java class without `@Configuration`:

```
public class NotAnnotatedConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DemoService demoService() {
        return new DemoService();
    }

}
```

I've tried to load this configuration in the following test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = NotAnnotatedConfiguration.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class NotAnnotatedConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired DemoService demoService;

    @Test
    public void load() {
        assertNotNull(this.demoService);
    }

}
```

And it works! I've got the same result in real applications, not only in tests.

Based on my tests, I think that `@Configuration` is necessary only when you want the class to be scanned by Spring, otherwise you can give a not annotated configuration to Spring and it will load and scan all the beans defined inside it. However, the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`'s javadoc doesn't seem so clear to me (probably I'm misunderstanding something):

```
/**
 * Create a new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, deriving bean definitions
 * from the given annotated classes and automatically refreshing the context.
 * @param annotatedClasses one or more annotated classes,
 * e.g. {@link Configuration @Configuration} classes
 */
public AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Class<?>... annotatedClasses) {
    this();
    register(annotatedClasses);
    refresh();
}
```

I've created a github repository with my tests to share my conclusions: https://github.com/itelleria/configuration-annotation

The question is, despite working my tests, is it allowed not annotating with `@Configuration` the java configuration class in Spring?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right that Spring will load the config class and also create instances but will not treat the instances as beans. Meaning: other service which uses the `DemoService` will create several instances for each usage and not as a singleton which would be the default scope when created as a bean.

```
public class DemoServiceUsage {

    DemoService demoService;

    public DemoServiceUsage(DemoService demoService) {
        this.demoService = demoService;
    }
}

public class NotAnnotatedConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public DemoService demoService() {
        DemoService demoService = new DemoService();
        System.out.println("demoService " + demoService.hashCode());
        return demoService;
    }

    @Bean
    public DemoServiceUsage demoServiceUsage1() {
        return new DemoServiceUsage(demoService());
    }

    @Bean
    public DemoServiceUsage demoServiceUsage2() {
        return new DemoServiceUsage(demoService());
    }
}

@Configuration
@Import({
    NotAnnotatedConfiguration.class
})
public class ApplicationConfig {
}

@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationConfiguration.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class NotAnnotatedConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    DemoServiceUsage demoServiceUsage1;

    @Autowired
    DemoServiceUsage demoServiceUsage2;

    @Test
    public void load() {
        assertNotNull(this.demoServiceUsage1);
        assertNotNull(this.demoServiceUsage2);
    }
}
```

Here you will see that you get multiple demoService outputs with different hashCodes. If `demoService` would be a bean we should only see one instance as it should have a singleton scope.

Comment: Great point! I hadn't seen that difference and I think it can lead to big problems. Based on this, IMHO a java configuration class should be always annotated with `@Configuration` because some dependency injections might not work. I've added your example to my github repository. Thanks!

Comment: I think that has nothing to do with @Configuration annotation. With it, it still output two different hashcode

Answer (score 0):

Your case may not need [Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html), but first of all you can follow the convention of annotating class as design, and as you mention, when someone will work with component scan there'll be an issue, because you will need to add `@Component` or other meta-annotated:

> @Configuration is meta-annotated with @Component, therefore @Configuration classes are candidates for component scanning

Also in Configuration you can include component scanning:

> @Configuration classes may not only be bootstrapped using component scanning, but may also themselves configure component scanning using the @ComponentScan annotation:
>
> ```
>  @Configuration
>  @ComponentScan("com.acme.app.services")
>  public class AppConfig {
>      // various @Bean definitions ...
>  }
> ```

Comment: I agree with you, without `@Configuration` the java class can not be scanned. I was aware of that issue but it's something that I can deal with it.

Comment: @telle you can, but after a year another developer will try to search for Configuration files or use component scan and can miss the class

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wouldn't do this in any other situation, but for my particular case I believe we could manage without scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Just quoting what Spring Document says

> Full @Configuration vs “lite” @Bean mode?

> When @Bean methods are declared within classes that are not annotated with @Configuration, they are referred to as being processed in a “lite” mode. Bean methods declared in a @Component or even in a plain old class are considered to be “lite”, with a different primary purpose of the containing class and a @Bean method being a sort of bonus there. For example, service components may expose management views to the container through an additional @Bean method on each applicable component class. In such scenarios, @Bean methods are a general-purpose factory method mechanism.

> Unlike full @Configuration, lite @Bean methods cannot declare inter-bean dependencies. Instead, they operate on their containing component’s internal state and, optionally, on arguments that they may declare. Such a @Bean method should therefore not invoke other @Bean methods. Each such method is literally only a factory method for a particular bean reference, without any special runtime semantics. The positive side-effect here is that no CGLIB subclassing has to be applied at runtime, so there are no limitations in terms of class design (that is, the containing class may be final and so forth).

> In common scenarios, @Bean methods are to be declared within @Configuration classes, ensuring that “full” mode is always used and that cross-method references therefore get redirected to the container’s lifecycle management. This prevents the same @Bean method from accidentally being invoked through a regular Java call, which helps to reduce subtle bugs that can be hard to track down when operating in “lite” mode.

for more information visit [Basic Concepts: @Bean and @Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts)